# Wordpress inbound email action

Tags: php, wordpress

is it possible to setup an inbound email service on a Wordpress site that updates a table when specific users email a specific email address hosted on the Wordpress site?

Comment: I don't think so. You would be much better pressed to have a form on the site and then update a table in the database, then update a table on the website. That is probably your best bet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  PostmarkApp does just that. You can read more information about it on the below link.

- https://postmarkapp.com/developer/webhooks/inbound-webhook

But the gist of it is, you can setup an email forwarder on example@email.com to email postmarkapp@email.com (your postmark email address), then with the inbound webhook you can capture inbound emails and save them to your database.